# How to set up Smtplib in python

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I've been learning python online by myself for the past month. I'm currently getting into the Smtp packages an how to send Emails. However the way that the teacher explains how to allow python to access to my Email doesnt work for me.

We are suppose to allow less secure apps to access our email, though this function was removed by google last year, and the disable the two step verification process, yet Im not able to find how to do that.

I've been dealing with this issue for the past weeks and have no idea how to solve it.

[This is my email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/molra.png)
[This is how my security tab is supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLzKt.png)
[This is my security tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0h2b.png)
[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFk3Q.png)

Im not quite sure what to say here, other than everything basically hahahahah

im just desperate at this point

Comment: You didn't share any code and didn't point to a specific problem. I understand that your issue is that you wrote some code that would interact with a minimally secured (or unsecured) smtp server, and that Google doesn't allow you to set up for that. There's no way around that, but there are other email providers online that are less secure, or you could run your own smtp server (although that's probably harder than writing the script). Are you supposed to submit your work somewhere? How will it be checked? Do you have an example of code, and the problem it's supposed to solve?